# relating testimonials to multiple products with relationship field

Tags: relationships, related-entries

I have two channels, the main channel is showing a product, and on that single product page, I want to show testimonials that are related to the product.  The second channel is a testimonials channel.  Each entry on the testimonial channel can be related to several "products". I have a relationship field in the testimonial channel called {related_products} where the user can associate the testimonial to several products.  Can someone help me figure this out? I am not sure if testimonial or products is the parentChannel.

here is the code on the "Product" page:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="testimonials"}
   {related_products}
     {related_products:title}
   {/related_products}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Testimonials would be the parent channel Products are "children".

Your syntax looks ok, are you using any custom statuses in your Products channel? If so try adding a statuses parameter to the relationship field tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="testimonials"}
   {related_products status="not closed"}
     {related_products:title}
   {/related_products}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```